# ColReorder is not working in Responsive DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, laravel-datatables

I have DataTables and implemented the `colReorder` by dragging the `checkbox` element using `.sortable() jquery-ui` and everything is fine. But when I enable `responsive:true` the column is not ordering any more.

The reorder index is stored from DB and fetch using ajax..

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    responsive: true,
});
$.get('{{ url('/get-ranks') }}', function(response) {
    var ranks = response.data; // Output: 2, 3, 1, 0, 6, 4, 5

    table.colReorder.reset();
    var order = ranks.split(',').map(function(i) {
        return parseInt(i, 10);
    });

    table.colReorder.order(order);
});
```

The `order` variable gives the exact indexes, but still not working.

I just want to reorder the columns as well as the hidden columns from responsive.

I create a working test case here http://live.datatables.net/mulibiwi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
   table.columns.adjust()
  .responsive.recalc();
```

will recalculate the columns and redraw table.